# How to avoid polymorphism in superclass query when using JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, entity

I use spring jpa+hibernate to connect to an Oracle DB with 2 tables: `Customers` and `LegacyCustomers`.

`Customers` extends `LegacyCustomers` by adding some **additional** columns.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Customers")
public class Customers extends LegacyCustomers {
    @Column(name="NewId") private String newId;
    @Column(name="PhoneNumber") private String phoneNumber;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="LegacyCustomers")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class LegacyCustomers {
    @Column(name="OldId") private String oldId;
    @Column(name="Name") private String name;
    @Column(name="Address") private String address;
}
```

However they are completely different tables. I am looking for a way to express the relationship in java but avoid the polymorphism that hibernate creates when querying the superclass table (`LegacyCustomers`). How can I tell hibernate to use only columns from the superclass when I query for `LegacyCustomers`?

<strike>Unfortunately the `@Polymorphism` annotation suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44418404/how-do-i-get-hibernate-to-ignore-subclasses) doesnt help.</strike>

Thanks for the help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get Hibernate to ignore subclasses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44418404/how-do-i-get-hibernate-to-ignore-subclasses)
The `@Polymorphism(type=PolymorphismType.EXPLICIT)` annotation on the subclass `Customers` works fine.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? do you not want results from the Customers table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve your goal, you need to use the `@MappedSuperclass` annotation instead to a new `BaseCustomers` class that encapsulates the common properties:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseCustomers {
    @Column(name="OldId") private String oldId;
    @Column(name="Name") private String name;
    @Column(name="Address") private String address;
}
```

Afterward, the `LegacyCustomers` just extend the `BaseCustomers` and only adds the `@Entity` annotation since the `BaseCustomers` is not treated as an entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="LegacyCustomers")
public class LegacyCustomers extends BaseCustomers {

}
```

And the `Customers` entity does the same:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Customers")
public class Customers extends BaseCustomers {
    @Column(name="NewId") private String newId;
    @Column(name="PhoneNumber") private String phoneNumber;
}
```

That's it.